# Help Plotting in Mathematica

Tags: math-software, mathematica

I have a function of the form S=f(x,y,z), 0 ≤ x ≤ 1,0 ≤ y ≤ 1, 0 ≤ z ≤ 1. I would like to solve S=0 numerically and plot the solution set of (x,y,z) in 3-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `ContourPlot3D[]` for this:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```